# How do I know what the server is doing when crashing?

Tags: linux, centos, kernel

I have a server running on Centos 5.2 and is there any a better way to know why the server crashed or what it's doing at that time?

I am sorry I am a newbie and any help is appreciated~ Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have experienced a kernel panic, you can set up a remote kernel console to capture all the data that might be lost on the local console (especially if the crash is from a non-maskable interrupt, which tends to reboot the system).

On the system that you expect might crash:

```
/sbin/modprobe netconsole netconsole=6666@10.1.1.16/eth0,6666@10.1.1.17/00:19:BB:31:B8:0E
```

- 6666 is an arbitrary port number
- 10.1.1.16 is the IP address of the local interface to send via
- eth0 is the name of the local interface to send via
- 10.1.1.17 is the IP address of the remote interface to send to
- 00:19:BB:31:B8:0E is the MAC address of the remote interface to send to

On the remote system, run (this requires that you have netcat installed):

```
nc -l -p 6666 -u | tee capture.file
```

This will capture all kernel output on the remote system.  This runs at a much lower level (the same point in the kernel that writes to /dev/klog), so you may see the very last bit of information that the kernel outputs when it panics even if syslog et. al have stopped operating.

Comment: I know there is a way of dumping kernel core when crashing. But is it the only most often used method to do so? any other way? I mean some other feasible and effective solutions

Comment: +1 on the netconsole. I've been meaning to write a blog post about this for some time since IMO it's one of the best kernel debugging tools you can have. It's helped me solve numerous problems.

Comment: +1 on the netconsole, too. I've been searching for such a solution some time ago and didn't find any appropriate solution.

Answer (score 4):

try starting process accounting

`/etc/init.d/psacct start` or `/sbin/chkconfig psacct on` (for autostart on boot)

then use lastcomm(1) to see what was running when.

or try installing [atop](http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/packages/atop/), it will log your machine memory and process state every 10 minutes so you can get an idea what was going on.

`atop -r /var/log/atop/atop_YYYYMMDD` and then use t and T keys to go forwards and backwards

in 99% of the cases it is clear from those two exactly what was going on

Comment: +1 Very interesting. I must admit I had never used lastcomm et al. before.

Comment: Keeping track of what has been running in useland may give you a clue, but it's not really going to help. Getting a core and looking into it is the only way to be sure. When the panic happens, the kernel isn't going to spend anytime writing out log files, the important log, the kernel ring buffer, isn't going to get dumped to the filesystem.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this way and I guess it might be some easier than kernel dumping~

Comment: Geoff, the goal here is to first try easier ways and bring in the heavy artillery only if necessary. In the last 15 years I had servers crashing front and center and only one time I had to resort to kernel dumps or network logging.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked /var/log/dmesg, /var/log/messages, and /var/log/syslog?

Comment: yes, but there is nothing helps. ( I have no /var/log/syslog on my server, is that normal?)

Comment: Yes, it is. On Centos and RHEL you have /var/log/messages and /var/log/dmesg, no /var/log/syslog

Comment: Normal logs are only likely to be of use if there is a piece of hardware that is failing slowly. As there is nothing there, this is a sudden failure, so it's either a kernel problem, tainted kernel mod problem or sudden hardware failure.

Answer (score 2):

What sort of crash?  Everyone's recommendation about dmesg / messages logs are good.  If it is just 'shutting off' before it has the chance to log anything, I would guess it might be overheating or there is a power supply problem.

If this is the case, it might be helpful to go to the hardware logs if they exist.  If you use Dell servers, Dell support can give you Linux tools to access these logs.  Other vendors might provide similar functionality.

You might also check the memory with [memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/).

Comment: +1 for memtest recommendation. I've been bit by bad ram so many times...

Answer (score 1):

Collecting a core over the network is probably overkill, you can dump it locally. [This is a guide](http://prefetch.net/blog/index.php/2009/07/06/using-kdump-to-get-core-files-on-fedora-and-centos-hosts/) for setting up and testing kdump. If you follow the instructions and still can't get a dump created locally then you should then move on to capturing over the network..

Of course once you have a core dump, you'll need to do some analysis on it using the [crash](http://people.redhat.com/anderson/crash_whitepaper/) utility. You'll need to install the right [kernel-debuginfo](http://debuginfo.centos.org/) rpm for your running kernel and then invoke crash - you should get the general gist from the whitepaper. If you can get it open the first thing you should look at is the log - scroll down to the bottom and you should get some clues as to what is going on at the time the crash occurs.

Comment: I like this answer, but core dumping over the network is not much trouble to set up than dumping locally. Don't know why I suggested the network dump though; probably needed some coffee at the time :P Anyway, +1 for pointing at the guide and whitepaper.

Answer (score 0):

You could configure the machine to do a kernel core dump over the network, but you'd still need someone skilled to look into that.